# Lost Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I installed my drivers for my Nvidia graphics card, and when I went to config using the command: `sudo nvidia-xconfig` I got the message:

```
WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Now when I type in the command I get the message:

```
Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

What the hell is going on?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or use the ` to separate what is output and input?

Comment: input  = "sudo nvidia-xconfig"

Comment: output = "WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf" and "Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'"

Answer (score 1):

Well, everything is perfectly ok: In the first run no xorg.conf was present, so xconfig reported so:

```
WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.
```

It created a xorg.conf still:

```
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

In the second run the xorg.conf was already present:

```
Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
```

So it has been backed up:

```
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
```

and a new one has been created in its place:

```
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

Of course, if you didn't change the xorg.conf between the two runs, both the backed up and the new version are identical.

Comment: so, no need to configure the driver....?

Comment: Depends on what you want. The driver runs even without generating a xorg.conf, but if you want to use some specific settings you can of course generate and modify it. Some settings can also be applied through the graphical nvidia-settings utility.